How to debug asyncio warning in base_events.py:1931?
I've written a chat app that uses Quart, socketio, and uvicorn, along with some external frameworks like firestore. My dev environment is Replit. In some parts of my app, I get vague warning messages that I interpret as meaning that something is blocking an async function:
WARNING
Executing <Task pending name='Task-32' coro=<AsyncServer._handle_event_internal() running at /home/runner/MyApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/socketio/async_server.py:610> wait_for=<Task pending name='Task-33' coro=<UnaryStreamCall._send_unary_request() running at /home/runner/MyApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py:634> cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /home/runner/MyApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py:629> cb=[set.discard()] created at /nix/store/f98g7xbckgqbkagdvpzc2r6lv3h1p9ki-python3-3.11.9/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py:680> took 0.109 seconds

It occurs at base_events.py on line 1931. How do you debug this kind of problem?

Your asyncio loop is in debug mode, and you are getting a "slow callback duration" warning.  See the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#enabling-debug-mode.

That is indeed the documentation. Care to comment on the actual question?

Sure, I'll comment.  The message is neither a Warning nor an Exception but a sort of advisory.  It's informing you about a potential performance issue - there is an asyncio callback that takes longer than 0.1 seconds, the default threshold.  So your asyncio loop will occasionally be busy for that long, and unable to switch tasks during that interval.  You describe it as a "problem" but that depends entirely on your requirements.  If you decide that it's not a problem then there is nothing to debug; you could turn off debugging mode, change the threshold or simply ignore it.  Up to you.

"I interpret as meaning that something is blocking an async function"  Not quite.  "Something" is always blocking async functions, because async functions yield back to the event loop only when an await expression is encountered.  The message is informing you that more than 0.1s elapsed between await expressions.  This could be a long mathematical calculation, for example, no single statement of which would be described as "blocking" in the standard sense of the word.  "Blocking" usually means that a thread is waiting on an external event, such as a network transaction.

Right. What I'm asking is if there is a way to more easily determine what specific async function is being blocked, or better yet what the specific blocking code is. I actually know where to look in the particular instance of this warning because I've very familiar with the source, but that won't always be the case, and finding this with brute force by wrapping various blocks of code in timers doesn't strike me as the proper way to do this. Even with asyncio debug mode there doesn't seem to be any useful extra info.
